# Unable to post to Facebook feeds

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-graph-api, feed

I am trying to post a message on my friend’s timeline. I am using the following code. I have the proper access token too but still I can’t post. Can you pleases have a look here is the code.

```
<script> 
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var token = "<?php echo $_SESSION['access_token'];?>";

alert()token; 


        $.post(
            "https://graph.facebook.com/<?php echo $sqlr['regidfriendsid']; ?>/feed", 
            {
                picture: "http://my.com/hi.jpg",
                link: "https://www.my.com/login.php?ref=owall",
                privacy: '{value: "EVERYONE"}',
                access_token: token,
                name: 'Facebook Dialogs',
                caption: 'Reference Documentation',
                message: " Click to see more? "
            }
        );
   });
</script>
```

I dont know why I am getting this error .

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "An access token is required to request this resource.",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "code": 104
    }
}
```

Comment: Some problem with your `access_token` Please validate your access token here: [Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug)

Comment: @Sahil - Its a Valid Token. I checked it just now on the debugger. I even kept an alert(token) right after var token = `"<?php echo $_SESSION['access_token'];?>";` and it gives me the value . Is there any alternative to this ?

Comment: use THIS token and try posting using the graph api explorer once.

Comment: Did you try puting access token in url like this
https://graph.facebook.com/?access_token="+token+"/<?php echo $sqlr['regidfriendsid']; ?>/feed

Answer (score 0):

Did you check that `$_SESSION['access_token']` is set? Chances are it's not, so you're passing an empty token to the API. You could probably check it at either serverside or clientside (php or javascript) and produce an error if it's not. If it is set, I would try to validate or regenerate your token with the Facebook API.

Comment: Yes it is set. I even kept an alert(token) right after `var token = "<?php echo $_SESSION['access_token'];?>";`  and it gives me the value